# django-rest-framework: Adding bulk operation in a ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have many endpoints which use `ModelViewSet` to manage CRUD operations for my models.

What I am trying to do, is to add bulk create, update, and delete at these same endpoints.  In other words, I want to add `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH` and `DELETE` to the collection endpoint (e.g.: `/api/v1/my-model`).  There is a `django-rest-framework-bulk` package available, but it seems to be abandoned (hasn't been updated in 4 years) and I'm not comfortable using a package in production that is no longer active.

Additionally, There are several similar questions here that have solutions, as well as blog posts I've found.  However, they all seem to use the base `ViewSet`, or `APIView`, which would require re-writing all of my existing `ModelViewSet` code.

Finally, there is the option of using the `@action` decorator, however this would require me to have a separate list endpoint (e.g.- `/api/v1/my-model/bulk`) which I'd like to avoid.

Are there any other ways to accomplish this while keeping my existing `ModelViewSet` views?  I've been looking at `GenericViewSet` and mixins, and am wondering if creating my own mixin might be the way to go.  However, looking at the mixin code, it doesn't appear that you can specify an HTTP Request method to be attached to a given mixin.

Finally, I have tried creating a separate `ViewSet` that accepts PUT and adding it to my URLs, but this doesn't work (I get a 405 Method not allowed when I try to PUT to `/api/v1/my-model`).  The code I tried looks like this:

```py
# views.py
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    paginator = None

class ListMyModelView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def put(self, request):
        # Code for updating list of models will go here.

        return Response({'test': 'list put!'})


# urls.py
router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'my-model', MyModelViewSet)
router.register(r'my-model', ListMyModelView, base_name='list-my-model')

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    # more paths for auth, admin, etc..
]
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you said you wanted to avoid adding an extra action but in my opinion it's the simplest way to update your existing views for bulk create/update/delete.

You can create a mixin that you add to your views that will handle everything, you'd just be changing one line in your existing views and serializers.

Assuming your `ListSerializer` look similar to the [DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-update) the mixins would be as follows.

**core/serializers.py**

```
class BulkUpdateSerializerMixin:
    """
    Mixin to be used with BulkUpdateListSerializer & BulkUpdateRouteMixin
    that adds the ID back to the internal value from the raw input data so
    that it's included in the validated data.
    """
    def passes_test(self):
        # Must be an update method for the ID to be added to validated data
        test = self.context['request'].method in ('PUT', 'PATCH')
        test &= self.context.get('bulk_update', False)
        return test

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        ret = super().to_internal_value(data)

        if self.passes_test():
            ret['id'] = self.fields['id'].get_value(data)

        return ret
```

**core/views.py**

```
class BulkUpdateRouteMixin:
    """
    Mixin that adds a `bulk_update` API route to a view set. To be used
    with BulkUpdateSerializerMixin & BulkUpdateListSerializer.
    """
    def get_object(self):
        # Override to return None if the lookup_url_kwargs is not present.
        lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field
        if lookup_url_kwarg in self.kwargs:
            return super().get_object()
        return

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Initialize serializer with `many=True` if the data passed
        # to the serializer is a list.
        if self.request.method in ('PUT', 'PATCH'):
            data = kwargs.get('data', None)
            kwargs['many'] = isinstance(data, list)
        return super().get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        # Add `bulk_update` flag to the serializer context so that
        # the id field can be added back to the validated data through
        # `to_internal_value()`
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        if self.action == 'bulk_update':
            context['bulk_update'] = True
        return context

    @action(detail=False, methods=['put'], url_name='bulk_update')
    def bulk_update(self, request, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            queryset,
            data=request.data,
            many=True,
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Then you would just inherit from the mixins

```
class MyModelSerializer(BulkUpdateSerializerMixin
                        serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        list_serializer_class = BulkUpdateListSerializer

class MyModelViewSet(BulkUpdateRouteMixin,
                     viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
```

And your PUT request would just have to point to `'/api/v1/my-model/bulk_update'`

**Updated mixins that don't require extra viewset action:**

For bulk operations submit a POST request to the list view with data as a list.

```
class BulkUpdateSerializerMixin:
    def passes_test(self):
        test = self.context['request'].method in ('POST',)
        test &= self.context.get('bulk', False)
        return test

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        ret = super().to_internal_value(data)

        if self.passes_test():
            ret['id'] = self.fields['id'].get_value(data)

        return ret
```

In `get_serializer()` there's a check to ensure that only POST requests can be accepted for bulk operations. If it's a POST and the request data is a list then add a flag so the ID field can be added back to the validated data and your `ListSerializer` can handle the bulk operations.

```
class BulkUpdateViewSetMixin:
    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
        if self.request.method in ('POST',):
            data = kwargs.get('data', None)
            is_bulk = isinstance(data, list)
            kwargs['many'] = is_bulk
            kwargs['context']['bulk'] = is_bulk
        return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(request.data, list):
            return self.bulk_update(request)
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def bulk_update(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            queryset,
            data=request.data,
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I've tested that this works but I have no idea how it will affect API schema documentation.

Comment: I probably should have been more specific in my OP.  The issue is that the owner of said API, has explicitly stated- "This must be a 100% flat API, and follow REST conventions".  We all know that everyone has different opinions on what "following REST conventions" means, and in this particular PMs mind, it means that every action is done through HTTP methods, not additional url paths.  In an email to him earlier asking if we could just add a `/bulk` onto the end of a collection url, his response was "Absolutely not."

Comment: I guess that would mean that you're limited to POST requests from the list endpoint? This will become more difficult to document but I guess that wasn't included in the OP. I've updated my answer.

Comment: In my specs there is no limitation.  Ideally, each collection endpoint would allow POST to create a new instance, then PATCH, PUT, and DELETE to modify multiple.  The code to implement seems straightforward to me.  It is the routing code that allows a collection endpoint to accept PATCH, PUT, and DELETE that I am unclear on.

Comment: I was able to combine this idea, along with adding a mappings to my routes, to get everything working the way required.  Thanks!